# JavaEE 6: How to inject JMS Resource in a standalone JMS client?

Tags: jms, java-ee-6, glassfish-3, message-driven-bean

I can't get `javax.jms.ConnectionFactory` injected into my standalone JMS client. 
I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException` at `connectionFactory.createConnection()` in the code below.

**JmsClient.java**

```
public class JmsClient {

    @Resource(mappedName="jms/QueueConnectionFactory")
    private static ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;    

    @Resource(mappedName="jms/ShippingRequestQueue")
    private static Destination destination;

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        try {
            Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
            connection.start();

            Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
            ObjectMessage message = session.createObjectMessage();

            ShippingRequestQueue shippingRequest = new ShippingRequestQueue(1, "107, Old Street");

            message.setObject(shippingRequest);
            producer.send(message);
            session.close();
            connection.close();

            System.out.println("Shipping request message sent ..");
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }        
    }

}
```

I have created the corresponding Connection Factory and Destination Resource at **Open MQ** (MoM) using Glassfish 3.1 Admin Console.

Could someone help me understand what am I missing?

Comment: `@Resource` doesn't work but looking up using JNDI name does.         `Context jndiContext = new InitialContext();
         
         ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) jndiContext.lookup("jms/QueueConnectionFactory");
         Queue destination = (Queue) jndiContext.lookup("jms/ShippingRequestQueue");`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Resource injection works only in a managed environment, such as a Java EE application server, or a Spring container, for instance. **In a standalone application JNDI is your only choice**.

Annotations in general are meant to be processed by some tool/framework, and plain JVM that executes your `main()` method simply does not contain such. The only annotations I know of that are processed by JVM out of the box are compile-time `@Deprecated`, `@Override` and `@SuppressWarnings`.

**Replying to your comment:** I don't have access to the book, so I'll only guess that they probably describe running an *application client component* and **not** *standalone application client*. It's not the same — [check Glassfish EJB FAQ](http://glassfish.java.net/javaee5/ejb/EJB_FAQ.html#AppClientDef). ACCs are normally deployed into an application server and can be executed via Java Web Start or without it, but in an AS-specific way. See [Glassfish example](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19798-01/821-1752/fvyme/index.html#6nmndgn0d) (you didn't say what AS your EJB executes in).

Comment: `public class ShippingRequestJMSProducer {
    @Resource(name = "jms/ShippingRequestQueue", mappedName = "ShippingRequestQueue")
    private static Destination destination;

    @Resource(name = "jms/QueueConnectionFactory")
    private static ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
 // rest of the code
    }
}
`. This is a part of the code from chapter 4 from the book **EJB 3 in Action**. Dependency injection of resources are being done in this standalone client. How does it work?

Comment: Right. With **gf-client.jar** in build path you could only use the `lookup` method with JNDI name to get to resources. But for dependency injection to work in a standalone client it needs to be deployed to an EJB container to get that extra JavaEE juice. http://www.ensode.net/glassfish_rich_ejb_clients.html was useful. With Glassfish 3.1 `appclient -client myappclient.jar` works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

@skip: try     `@Resource(name="jms/QueueConnectionFactory") instead of     @Resource(mappedName="jms/QueueConnectionFactory")`

name=JNDI name as per javax.annotation.Resource java doc.

Comment: I tried `@Resource(lookup="jms/QueueConnectionFactory")` as well but still I am getting the same error as mentioned above as I am not able to get the resources injected.

Comment: @skip, this is strange. Because if you look at link:- http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/annotation/Resource.html  attribute name related to JNDI name. Did you try to resolve this JNDI name explicitly through NamingContext API?

Comment: @ag112- I've tried server specific `mappedName`, portable `name` and the new 'lookup' from JavaEE 6 but I am not able to get the resource injected. Only way it worked was when I did the following: `Context jndiContext = new InitialContext(); 
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) jndiContext.lookup("jms/QueueConnectionFactory"); 
Queue destination = (Queue) jndiContext.lookup("jms/ShippingRequestQueue");`. I've tried appending `java:comp/env` appended explicitly with the JNDI names above as well, which I shouldn't, but that doesn't work either. What am I missing here?